# C++ GUI database programming

Tags: c++, database

What is the `easiest` way for GUI database programming using C++ and where I can find a lot of tutorials and documentation?

I looked at `Qt`, but didn't find good tutorials on doing that.

What do you think of `MFC`? Any resources to recommend for this?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by GUI database programming? Just writing an application with a GUI, which interacts with/manipulates a database? Qt should be okay for that indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows I would definitely use Windows Forms. Otherwise, as you have mentioned: QT (I find QT documentation to be pretty good).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just targetting Windows, I'd seriously look at [Embarcadero C++ Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder).

The C++ compiler is not as compliant as some, but the VCL framework is ideal for GUI development, and comes with database-aware components straight out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention MFC, I assume you're on Windows.  Why not [Visual Studio C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/)? It has a GUI builder that creates basic WinForms. There's plenty of documentation and tutorials on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/), especially for database interaction (as long as your database is Access, SQL Server, etc). While not fully featured, it is free.